# How do I access cookies set by passportjs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, passport.js

I really hope this isn't a stupid question but I suspect it is.  I've googled everything I can to understand what's going on but I still don't understand how to read cookies that have been set using nodejs/express/passport.

I'm using Angular's ngCookies and $cookies service but when I try to print out the cookies I set on the server side,  I see this (using console.log($cookies["connect.sess"]))

```
s:j:{"passport":{"user":{"id":1,"email":"xxxxxx@yyyy.com","role":"Admin"}}}.0lKpQzpgzCAjgkIayDkUiOLhktIYsohr61U/4xSwWFA
```

My cookie is in there. But it's all stored as a string with that other stuff surrounding it.  Should I be looking at a different object?  It won't let me access -->

```
$cookies["connect.sess"].passport
```

because that's undefined which makes sense since $cookies["connect.sess"] returns a string.  Any hints as to where I'm going wrong here?  All I need to do is access these cookies that were set in the server.  I don't need to change them.  I'm hoping an extra set of eyes on this will do the trick.  I'm stumped!

I tried setting my own cookies by using res.cookie.  On the server side where I am creating the cookie it looks fine.  But somewhere between there and angular, it looks like "j:{my json cookie}"  This time no s: in front and no gobble-de-gook on the end.  Sure I can parse that stuff out and find my json, but where is this stuff getting added and why?

I did some poking around and the express response.cookie adds the j: in front of the json if you pass in an object.  and the s: with the blurb after the json object is their way of signing a cookie.  So I found that I didn't really need the session cookies that passports was sending.  I could just use the userid in the session cookies for authentication on the server side and create my own email and role cookies created using:

```
res.cookie("email", user.email, {my cookie options}) 
res.cookie("role", user.role, {my cookie options})
```

instead of trying to populate the session cookies with a json object.  The answer I've chosen below is the best option given what I know today.  Although I find it hard to believe that you have to strip characters off an object to get client cookies properly.  Seems odd.  I'm a cookie newbie, so if anyone has an explanation or a good link for reading I'd love to hear it.

Comment: if it helps anybody looking at this.  I'm using express 3 still. but the latest version of passport and angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are always stored as string, so that is the reason you are getting a string when you do console.log($cookies["connect.sess"]) and this string is the json representation of the object.

As your cookie has some non-json stuff, first you need to extract everything between the brackets "{}", then deserialize the string to a javascript object.

To deserialize a JSON string to a javascript object you must use angular.fromJson(json).

Example:

```
//'s:j:{"passport":{"user":{"id":1,"email":"xxxxxx@yyyy.com","role":"Admin"}}}.0lKpQzpgzCAjgkIayDkUiOLhktIYsohr61U/4xSwWFA';
var s = $cookies["connect.sess"];

// First extract json object from the crazy cookie string
//There is also an option to to this with regular expressions
var jsonString = s.substring(s.indexOf("{"), s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1);

// Then convert to a javascript object
var obj = angular.fromJson(jsonString);
var passport = obj.passport;
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: Right, I've tried that and I get the following error:

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
        at Object.parse (native)
        at Object.fromJson     (http://localhost:8888/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1134:14)

Comment: The string I'm getting is a json object, surrounded by non-jsony stuff which makes attempts at deserialization fail.

Comment: Got it, is "s:j:{real stuff}.0lhktIYsohr61U/4xSwWFA" what you are getting ? I'll post in my answer a way to "extract" the jason string.

Comment: Yes.  The "s:j{this is my cookie json}.0lKpQzpgzCAjgkIayDkUiOLhktIYsohr61U/4xSwWFA" is what's in $cookies["connect.sess"]